# Opening tkinter in python 3.4.2 in Ubuntu 14 LTS

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, tkinter, ubuntu-14.04

I just installed Ubuntu 14 LTS as a virtual machine and I tried installing python 3.4.2. And python 2.7.6 is pre-installed on Linux. I tried opening the IDLE3 for python 3.4.2 it says 
"Your Python may not be configured for Tk. **". So my question why IDLE is not opening and how to configure my ubuntu to work with 3.4.2 and idle as default. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python will not compile tkinter if you didn't install build depency for it.

By issuing the following command (followed by Python reinstallation) will solve your problem:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3-tk
```

Above command will install package to satisfy build dependency for tkinter.

---

BTW, if you are okay with Python-3.4.0 (not Pyhton-3.4.2), instead of building yourself, consider using `python3` and `python3-tk` package.

Comment: wow thanks for the quick reply. And I installed tk-dev and re-installed it. Now it works.

Comment: It is actually _tkinter.c, not tkinter.py that is not being compiled.  But same difference to the user unless one goes looking through the Python directories to see what is missing.